# Remove Twilio's "please press 4 6"

Tags: twilio

Its weird when you can't find a single mention of something on the net.

How do you remove the "please press X Y" prompt at the beginning of Twilio calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found it for you:

`Calls to and from your free trial phone number will play a short trial message before your TwiML runs.`

It's mentioned here: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136107-How-does-Twilio-s-Free-Trial-work-

To start using your Twilio phone number without these restrictions, just upgrade your account.

Comment: Thanks for that!  My account has been upgraded, and I've recharged it 3x now so I'll msg support, its a provisioning goof.  I've even bought a bunch of numbers!  Again thanks!

Comment: Filed a ticket with helpdesk, we'll see!